# C program that calculates weekly pay and overtime pay not working? Debugging

Tags: c, debugging

I'm creating a program that calculates the weekly pay, then any overtime pay is 1.5 times the normal pay rate for that week.
My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  double payrate;
  double hours;
  double weeklypay = hours * payrate;
  double overtimehours = hours - 40;
  double overtimepay = weeklypay * 1.5;
  double overtimesalary =  weeklypay + (overtimehours * overtimepay);

  printf("What is your standard hourly pay rate?\n");
  scanf("%d",&payrate);
  printf("How many hours do you work in a week?\n");
  scanf("%d",&hours);

  if (hours <= 40)
    printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", weeklypay);

  else
    printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", overtimesalary);

  return 0;
}
```

However the program continues to not work and I don't understand why? Instead of giving me an answer I always get an answer for weekly pay as "1". Or if I give an answer with a decimal I get an answer of 0. Like this:

```
What is your standard hourly pay rate?
2
How many hours do you work in a week?
2
This means your weekly pay is 1 .
```

What am I doing that's wrong? I'm new to C so forgive me for my ignorance but I could really use some help as I've spent all day trying to figure out why.

Comment: First payrate and hours contain some unknown numbers. Then you calculate hours\*payrate (i.e. unknown number \* unknown other number) and store that (which is also unknown) in weeklypay. Then you do some other stuff like asking the user for their hours and payrate. Then you print the number you previously stored in weeklypay, which of course hasn't changed because nothing caused it to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `scanf`, you're using the `%d` format specifier, which expects the address of an `int`, but you're passing the address of a `double`.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior.

For `double`, use the `%lf` format specifier.

```
scanf("%lf",&payrate);
....
scanf("%lf",&hours);
```

You're also operating on values *before* you read any values into them.  You need to read in the values first, *then* do the calculations on them.

Answer (score 0):

You have some statements in the wrong order. You need to move the calculations:

```
double weeklypay = hours * payrate;
double overtimehours = hours - 40;
double overtimepay = weeklypay * 1.5;
double overtimesalary =  weeklypay + (overtimehours * overtimepay);
```

down after your code that does the input. Otherwise you're not operating on any meaningful numbers.

Also, your `scanf` and `printf` formats doesn't match your variable type. Use `%lf` for `double` variables in `scanf` and `%f` for `printf`.

Finally, turn on, read and *pay attention to* your compiler warnings. All of this is reported clearly by any reasonably recent (read: last 20 years) compiler.

Answer (score 0):

See my comments

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  double payrate;
  double hours;
  double weeklypay = hours * payrate; // Here payrate does not have a value nor does hours
  double overtimehours = hours - 40; // Ditto with hours 
  double overtimepay = weeklypay * 1.5; // From above this is not defined
  double overtimesalary =  weeklypay + (overtimehours * overtimepay); // ...

  printf("What is your standard hourly pay rate?\n");
  scanf("%d",&payrate); // Check the return value from scanf
  printf("How many hours do you work in a week?\n");
  scanf("%d",&hours); // See above

 // Here you are on your own...
  if (hours <= 40)
    printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", weeklypay);

  else
    printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", overtimesalary);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int payrate;
int hours;
printf("What is your standard hourly pay rate? \n");
scanf("%d",& payrate);
printf("How many hours do you work in a week? \n");
scanf("%d",& hours);

int weeklypay = hours * payrate;
int overtimehours = hours - 40;
int overtimepay = weeklypay * 1.5;
int overtimesalary =  weeklypay + (overtimehours * overtimepay);


if (hours <= 40)
printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", weeklypay);

else
printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", overtimesalary);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's often much more helpful to explain what is wrong, and why a different solution would work. Just posting code isn't always what the person asking the question is after.